# format of web api respons is not correct

Tags: asp.net-web-api

request is present "accept: application/xml; charset=utf-8" but response content is json

Request:
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8

Response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 07 Jan 2019 17:11:14 GMT
Content-Length: 31

{"cod":1,"msg":"","data":"100"}

Comment: Request's `Content-Type` header tells the server what format the client is sending. Response's `Content-Type` header tells the client the format that the server is sending. Nothing is wrong here.

Comment: in request i set Accept to application / xml; when webservices respons contend must formated in xml but it is json.

request's Accept header tells the server what format the client wants

Comment: @user3359822 are developing api using asp.net core?

Answer (score 1):

software is developerd with .net framework 4.6.1

I noticed that if I return an anonymous class this will be serialized in json and never in xml.

to solve the problem, just return a non-anomalous calsse and it will be serialized correctly.